# SQL запрос, который выведет все возможные сочетания из одного столбца

Tags: sql

```sql
DECLARE @Colors TABLE(Name nvarchar(20))
INSERT INTO @Colors
VALUES ('green'),
('black'),
('yellow'),
('blue'),
('white'),
('red'),
('brown')
```

Необходимо написать SQL запрос который выведет результат в 4 столбца(Name1,Name2,Name3,Name4)все возможные сочетания  для значений переменной, где n = 7(семь цветов) и k = 4(четыре различных цвета в одной строке)

Пример для 4 цветов и 3 столбцов. Результат такой

| Name1 | Name2 | Name3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| green | black | yellow |
| blue | black | green |
| blue | black | yellow |
| green | blue | yellow |

Это тестовое задание. Ни как не подступиться, у меня есть представление о базовых запросах SQL, здесь для меня, что-то не тривиальное. Мне даже сложно оценить сложность этой задачи. Возможно решение простое, просто еще не достаточно опыта и практики. Буду очень благодарен если подскажите в каком направлении двигаться. Что попробовать. Благодарю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.color color1, 
       t2.color color2, 
       t3.color color3, 
       t4.color color4
FROM @Colors t1
JOIN @Colors t2 ON t2.color NOT IN (t1.color)
JOIN @Colors t3 ON t3.color NOT IN (t1.color, t2.color)
JOIN @Colors t4 ON t4.color NOT IN (t1.color, t2.color, t3.color);
```

---

> нужно будет исключить повторения, чтобы в каждой строке были только уникальные сочетания цветов.

```sql
SELECT t1.color color1, 
       t2.color color2, 
       t3.color color3, 
       t4.color color4
FROM @Colors t1
JOIN @Colors t2 ON t2.color > t1.color
JOIN @Colors t3 ON t3.color > t2.color
JOIN @Colors t4 ON t4.color > t3.color;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ac66dce349ed1d8abbe3974a0927c801)

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: У меня в голове крутилось, что нужно использовать циклы или рекурсию, все оказалось проще, единственный момент, результат все же не тот, выводит все возможные варианты, нужно будет исключить повторения, чтобы в каждой строке были только уникальные сочетания цветов. Направление задано, буду разбираться дальше. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Ну что вам сказать, меня потрясает как быстро вы даете совершенно не очевидные мне ответы. Я пытался с Group BY, DISTINCT, NOT EXIST и пр. В который раз спасибо.